# How can I combine or merge the results of a string into an other string (implode included)

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

So I used implode to store the values of a POST method in a variable...

```
$xaraktiristika = implode(', ', $_POST['tlxar']);
```

which gives me the result of this string:

```
Sugar, Sugar-Type, Decaf, Quantity, Extra Syrup
```

and a second one:

```
  $choices = implode(', ', $_POST['epiloges_xar']);
```

which gives me the result of this string:

```
Medium-sugar, Brown, Yes, Double, No
```

Now I want to combine them so I can insert them into my database.

My question is can I combine these two so the result will be something like

```
Sugar:Medium-sugar, Sugar-Type:Brown, Decaf:Yes etc.
```

or should I do it in a differant way? I apologize if my question  does not make much sense but I am still learning all these stuff and English is not my mother language. XD

Here is the code if it helps:

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST["btn1"])) {
 
$xaraktiristika = implode(', ', $_POST['tlxar']);

echo $xaraktiristika;


echo"<br>";


  $epiloges_string = implode(', ', $_POST['epiloges_xar']);

 
  
 
  

$s="insert into kalathi_proion(id,
        id_session,
         id_proion,
          posothta,
           poso,
            id_xarakthristikou_proiontos,
             timi_xarakt,
              timi_euro_xarakt
               ) values

(NULL,
 '$sid',
  $_POST[idp],
   $_POST[quantity],
    $_POST[timi],
     '$xaraktiristika',
       '$choices',
       $_POST[tx]
        )";

mysqli_query($conn,$s);



echo $s;
 
}


 else 
  
{    
    echo "Error";
}



?>




  <?php 

echo " 

<div class='container pp1'>



  <div class=header1>
  <h4>ΚΑΦΕΔΕΣ</h4>
  </div>
  
  
  ";
 
 

$s="SELECT proionta.id as idproion, proionta.titlos as proionta_title,proionta.perigrafh as proionta_desc,proionta.timh as proionta_price
FROM proionta,katigories

WHERE proionta.id_katigorias=1
AND katigories.id=proionta.id_katigorias ";



$tb=mysqli_query($conn,$s);
 
 
 
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($tb))
   {
    echo "
    
       
       <div class=p1>
        <li><h4>$row[proionta_title]</h4> <h4 class=price id=val>$row[proionta_price]€</h4></li>
        <li><button class=btn id=btnShowModal data-toggle=modal data-target=#myModal$row[idproion]>Προσθήκη</button></li>
         <p>$row[proionta_desc]</p>
         <hr>
       </div>";
       
       
       
       
       
       
       
      echo" <!------------------------------------------------MODAL----------------------------------------------->";



 echo" <div class='modal fade' id='myModal$row[idproion]' role='dialog'> <!-------modal start-------------->
  
  <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
 
   <div class='modal-content'> <!-------modal content start-------------->
   
     <div class='modal-header'>      <!-------modal header-------------->
     
       <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal$row[idproion]'>&times;</button>
       <h4 class='modal-title'>Επιλογές</h4>
       
     </div>          <!-------end of modal header-------------->
  
  
  
     <div class='modal-body'>";
  
      $s2="SELECT *,xarakthristika.id as idxarakthristikou,xarakthristika_proiontwn.id_xarakthristika as idxappr 
  
       FROM  xarakthristika_proiontwn,xarakthristika
       
  
       WHERE xarakthristika_proiontwn.id_xarakthristika = xarakthristika.id
  
       AND xarakthristika_proiontwn.id_proionta= $row[idproion]";
  
       $tb2=mysqli_query($conn,$s2);
  
      
  
              echo "

       <form action='paragelia.php' method=post> 
       
  
        <input type=hidden value=$row[idproion] name=idp>  <!--id proiontos-->
       
        <input type='hidden' name=timi value='$row[proionta_price]'>  <!--timh proiontos-->  
       
        
       ";
    
  
         while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($tb2))
         {
      
     echo "
         <input type=hidden value='$row2[idxarakthristikou]' name=idpx> <!-- xarakthristika id -->
     
         <input type='hidden' name=tlxar[] value='$row2[titlos]'>
     ";   
     
     echo"         <label for='epiloges'>$row2[titlos]</label>
        
          <select id='epiloges' name=epiloges_xar[]>";
          
          
         $s3="SELECT * 
         
         FROM times_xarakthristikwn,xarakthristika
         
         WHERE times_xarakthristikwn.id_xarakthristikou=$row2[idxappr] 
         AND xarakthristika.id=$row2[idxappr] 
         ";
          $tb3=mysqli_query($conn,$s3);
        
        
        
        
        
          while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($tb3))
          {
          
        
     echo"             <option><span>$row3[onoma]</span></option><span style='font-size:8px;'>($row3[timh])</span>
     
          
           
     ";     
          }
           
           
           
     echo"      
         </select>
         
         <input type=hidden value='$row3[timh]' name=tx> <!-- timh a3ia epiloghs xarakt--> 
         <br>
     ";
         
         
         
         } 
       
  
  
       echo " 
       <div class='quantity'><!-----quantity start----->
       <h4>Ποσότητα:</h4>
       <input type='number' value='1' min='0' max='1000' step='1' id='qnt' name='quantity'/>

       </div> <!-----quantity end----->
  
  
  
       <div class='comments'><!-----comments start----->
        <p>Σχόλια</p>
        <textarea rows='4' cols='50'> </textarea>
       </div>      <!-----comments end----->";
  
  echo "
  

      
      
     </div><!-----end of modal body----->
  
  
  

    <div class='modal-footer'>
     <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='btn1' >Προσθήκη1</button>
    </div>
    
      

    
     </form>  
     ";
 


  
echo"

    
   </div><!-------modal content end-------------->
 </div> 
</div> 
<!------------------------------------------------END OF MODAL----------------------------------------------->
 ";




       
           
} 

echo"</div>";
  ?>





  <?php
include "down.php";
?>
```

I want to combine $xarakthristika and $choices in a single variable and insert them to database like I said at the beginning of the post.

Comment: are you sure that indexes of the arrays are matching always?

Comment: What do you want to use the output for, looks a bit like JSON.

Comment: I posted the code in case it helps

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

This answer starts a counter (`count = 0` because arrays start at 0) and using PHP's foreach loop, we cycle through the values in the `$xaraktiristika` array by using the `$count` variable. In the process, we add the current value in the `$choice` array (broken down to individual pieces as `$c`) in the format requested. After adding the pieces back together, `$count` is incremented by 1 and the process continues until all values in `$choice` are used.

```
<?php
$xaraktiristika = array("Sugar", "Sugar-Type", "Decaf", "Quantity", "Extra Syrup");
$choice = array("Medium-sugar", "Brown", "Yes", "Double", "No");
$count = 0;
foreach ($choice as $c) {
  echo $xaraktiristika[$count] . ":" . $c . ", ";
  $count = $count + 1;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

using `array_map` you can do it simply

```
$_POST['tlxar'] = array("Sugar", "Sugar-Type", "Decaf", "Quantity", "Extra Syrup");
$_POST['epiloges_xar'] = array("Medium-sugar", "Brown", "Yes", "Double", "No");

echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($a, $b) {
  return $a.':'.$b;
}, $_POST['tlxar'], $_POST['epiloges_xar']));
```

output:

```
Sugar:Medium-sugar, Sugar-Type:Brown, Decaf:Yes, Quantity:Double, Extra Syrup:No
```